# Rich text box to string not "equal to" original string when it wasn't changed

Tags: c#, wpf, richtextbox

I have a `WPF` application and in it I am using a rich text box to display xml for a work item, the xml is editable. There is a save button so if the user changes the xml they can save it back to the database. Now there are a couple other items that the user can edit and save back to the database, so it's kind of blanket save that has a prompt to update the editable items if they have changed from the original source.

- Is Item 1 not equal to Item 1 Orignal if so show prompt
- Is Item 2 not equal to Item 2 Orignal if so show prompt
- ect...

I am running into a problem when I update one of the other editable items, the prompt to update the xml is being shown when it shouldn't (because it wasn't changed so it should have been skipped over).

I am getting the text from the rich text box like so:

```
TextRange textRange = new TextRange(
    rtb_xmlBase.Document.ContentStart,
    rtb_xmlBase.Document.ContentEnd);

string newXmlBase = textRange.Text;
```

And then it does the check to see if it's different from the original xml string (`GetWorkItemXML` returns the original xml from the database):

```
if (!newXmlBase.Equals(bailyAccess.GetWorkItemXML(long.Parse(rowView.Row["workitemid"].ToString()))))
{
    MessageBoxButton btnMessageBox = MessageBoxButton.YesNo;
    MessageBoxImage icnMessageBox = MessageBoxImage.Warning;

    MessageBoxResult rsltMessageBox = MessageBox.Show("Are you sure you wish to update the XML Base?", "Update Work Item",
        btnMessageBox, icnMessageBox);

    switch (rsltMessageBox)
    {
        case MessageBoxResult.Yes:
            //if (!bailyAccess.UpdateWorkItemXML(long.Parse(rowView.Row["workitemid"].ToString()), newXmlBase))
                //tb_ErrorDetails.Text = "An error occured during update, please close this window and try again";
            break;

        case MessageBoxResult.No:
            break;
    }
}
```

So is there some kind of formatting difference, that I don't realize is there, between the a rich text box and an ordinary text box that would account for that change? Because when it was just an ordinary text box, it worked fine. I changed to a rich text box to do searches a bit easier. Or am I just not getting the text correctly?

---- Edit ----

I did a debug, as suggested, and there were `\r` and `\n` characters. I did a find and replace on them.

Now it seems like the only difference between the two is that the `newXmlBase` has escape characters around the XML schema:

```
"<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-16\"?><Transaction xmlns:xsi=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance\" xmlns:xsd=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema\">
```

Where as, the string from the `bailyAccess` does not:

```
"<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>  <Transaction xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
```

**The `bailyAccess` is using inherited classes from a core set of objects (and functions) that are in `VB`**. I wouldn't have thought that would have made a difference to so I didn't mention it before, but now it seems like it might matter.

Comment: Debug and check the value of `newXmlBase` and `bailyAccess.GetWorkItemXML(long.Parse(rowView.Row["workitemid"].ToString())`

Comment: @lll, I edited my question after doing the debug.

Comment: You answered your own question. You can see the difference.